# Kibana Timestamp - Custom Time Range

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have requirement on Timestamp Time range calculation for particular hours

Eg: if a document comes to kibana at 9AM i need to find how many document came from that time and waiting for further process from respective application below is the sample i need to find hour range, like from how many hours this document is waiting in queue to get processed
(< 2 hours)
(>= 2 hours and <12 hours)

Am using @timestamp to calculate but not getting output
Eg KQL query >> FieldName:somevalue and @timestamp <=2(hours)

please help me to solve this problem